# Protractor azure pipeline No element found Error

Tags: azure, protractor, azure-pipelines

My protractor tests work correctly on my machine but when start it on Azure pipeline all tests fail with No element found.

Do you have an idea wwhat is the problem

May be i miss something here.That is in my conf.js:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  // getPageTimeout: 15000,
  specs: ['specDAC.js'],
  rootElement: 'html',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1200,900"],
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN
    }
   },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000,
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I see 'element not found' it's typically signalizing that the page/AUT is not even loaded. It's hard to say without seeing actual code but I can assume that your test starts with navigating to some page. Try add some logging or wrap this part in to condition (e.g If 'login' button is present => click; else => console.log("something wrong")

Comment: @Aleksandr I agree. Most likely the problem is not in the code since it's working on you local. I'm trying to say here that, probably, you application is not loaded and Protractor tries to find elements on empty page

Comment: @Aleksandar as far as I can see you testing a non-angular application, am I right? If yes did you tried to increase waits (in specs) to some ridiculously large values?

Comment: @Aleksandar and one more question. When you run test on your local and everything is working do you run it in headless mode similar to pipeline? Or the browsers UI in on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code. The test is work on my machine. The problem is something in the pipeline or in conf.js. The pipeline cannot find any elements. The page is loaded i put an average waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok may be you are right. That is my code you can check it:

it('first test', async function(){
        await sleep(2000);

```
    await browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await sleep(8000);

    // login user
    await loginPage.get(testConf.loginUrl);
    await sleep(4000);
    await loginPage.setLoginCredentials(testConf.mmmClientUser, testConf.password);
```

The error is not find an element where put my email but locally it is work